# Magic function for auto-invoke in php

Tags: php

In my Class I have methods with the same prefix at the beginning.

> sendMessage()
>
> sendPhoto()
>
> sendDocument()

So what I need, is just somehow initialize another method in the class every time when these methods (with prefix) are initialized without putting anything in methods' body. 
Is there any way to do this out of the box? Some magic php function which triggers every time when method with prefix is invoked...

Comment: why without putting a call to this new method in the existing methods body?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"initialize"* in *"initialize another method in the class every time when these methods (with prefix) are initialized"*?

Comment: *Don't* implement `function sendMessage` at all and implement `function __call` instead…? Are you familiar with `__call`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method:

```
class MagickClass {
    public function __call($name, params = []) {
        if (strpos($name, 'send') === 0) {
            $this->process(strtolower(str_replace('send', '', $name)));
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Not found', 404);
        }
    }

    private function process($action) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! I really don't understand how could I forgot about this magic method.